# Will installing WUBI on a non-empty external hard drive damage other files?

Tags: software-installation, usb, wubi, external-hdd

Is there a real risk or known issues when installing a simple WUBI on an external USB drive?

I must stress that the drive is not empty - it is currently NTFS (winxp) and has documents on it.

As I understand, WUBI acts like a "virtualized" disk, meaning that it should not affect the other folders in the disk because it writes its own "image" in a folder. Is that correct?

(Please do not answer that it would be better doing on an empty disk - it is not currently an option for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed and uninstalled Wubi and had no problems with it affecting anything else. Yes it works like a virtual disk and you should have no problems at all. give it a try.